# Is assigning an object to itself a good idea?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, garbage-collection

I have two classes, RecordSet and Record. RecordSet has a Generic List(Of Record).

I can add objects to the list by calling my RecordSet.AddRecord(ObjRecord) function, which returns RecordSet. When the list has a count of 200, some processing occurs and a new RecordSet object is returned, otherwise itself is returned and the application can carry on adding Record objects to the list.

My concern is that there will be 200 objects of RecordSet until garbage collection does it's sweep. Is this a good idea?

```
Public Class RecordSet
  Private lstRecords As New List(Of Record)

  Public Function AddRecord(SomeVariable) AS RecordSet      
    lstRecords.Add(New Record())
    If lstRecords.Count = 200 Then
      Me.ProcessTheRecords()
      Return New RecordSet()
    Else
      Return Me
    End If
  End Function

  Private Sub ProcessTheRecords()
    'Do stuff in here
  End Sub

  Private Class Record
    Public Sub New()

    End Sub
  End Class
End Class
```

Then in my application I call:

```
Dim objRecordSet AS New RecordSet
For Each VariableName In SomeList
  objRecordSet = objRecordSet.AddRecord(VariableName)
Next
'Process the remaining objects in objRecordSet here.
```

Comment: That sounds like a poor design.

Comment: You are returning brand-new, empty recordsets from add, so the reference to the old ones is being lost. Storing something and losing the key is, at best, equivalent to not storing it at all. And at worse, a waste of code, cpu cycles, and system memory.

Comment: This seems like a question more suited to Programmers.SE or codereview.SE

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is really bad pratice, it's hard to follow the code for someone new and is a potential bug source. Instead of returning urself every time, change your design.

Change your function to this:

```
Public Sub AddRecord(SomeVariable)
    lstRecords.Add(New Record()) <--- should't you be doing something with SomeVariable?!
    If lstRecords.Count = 200 Then
        Me.ProcessTheRecords()
    end if
End Function


Private Sub ProcessTheRecords()
   'Do stuff in here
   Me.lstRecords.clear()
End Sub
```

Now AddRecord does exactly what it says it does - it adds a new record and modifies the recordSet. ProcessTheRecords does the processing, as its supposed to do, and if u need to clear the list container - oh well, just clear it.

I strongly recommed to read this wiki article about
[Cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29).

Just as a proposiontion, the AddRecord could be a function of return type `Boolean`, which indicates the success of the operation (maybe an error or exception can be raised by the processing function?).

It's much cleaner now, isn't it?